# PowerShell code to send files in each sub-folder as email attachments

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that would email as attachments, all files in each subfolder of C:\Reports\ together. For instance, if the subfolders are C:\Reports\ABC having a.txt, b.xml and c.jpg and C:\Reports\DEF having d.txt, e.xml and f.pdf, the code should email a.txt, b.xml and c.jpg in one email and d.txt, e.xml and f.pdf in another.

```cs
#Connection Details
$username = ”vallabhherlekar@gmail.com”
$password = ”Appya1979!”
$smtpServer = “smtp.gmail.com”

$Directory = Get-ChildItem “C:\Reports\” -Directory
foreach ($d in $Directory) {
    $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
    #Uncomment Next line for SSL  
    $smtp.EnableSsl = $true

    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential ($username, $password)

    $msg.From = "vallabhherlekar@gmail.com"
    $msg.To.Add(“vallabhherlekar@gmail.com”)
    $msg.Body=”Please See Attached Files”
    $msg.Subject = “Email with Multiple Attachments”

    Write-Host "Working on directory $($d.FullName)..."
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$($d.FullName)" -File
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        Write-Host “Attaching File :- ” $file.FullName
        $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList 
$file.FullName
        $msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)
    }
    $smtp.Send($msg)
    $attachment.Dispose();
    $msg.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask your question. Does something about the code you posted not work? Other than the incorrectly wrapped `$attachment = ...` line, that should be throwing an error, I mean.

Comment: Hi Ansgar. I've wrapped the line correctly in my code. 
When I run the code, I get the below results:-
Working on directory C:\Reports\ABC...
Attaching File :-  C:\Reports\ABC\a.txt
Attaching File :-  C:\Reports\ABC\b.txt
Attaching File :-  C:\Reports\ABC\c.txt
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
At C:\Users\vhvc\Desktop\EmailFiles.ps1:39 char:1
+ $smtp.Send($msg)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException

Comment: With the first sub-directory it loops through all files within it but gives the error Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s) while trying to execute smtp.Send($msg). With the second sub-directory, it doesn't loop through the files, but tries sending each file individually and gives the error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" while trying to execute $msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use the [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6) cmdlet? As a sidenote: replace all the curly 'smartquotes' with straight ones.

Comment: $Directory=Get-ChildItem "C:\Reports\" -Directory
$Cred = Get-Credential
Foreach($d in $Directory)
{
Write-Host "Working on directory $($d.FullName)..."
$files=Get-ChildItem -Path "$($d.FullName)" -File
Foreach($f in $files)
{
Write-Host  = "Attaching File :- " $f.FullName
$hash = @{
    from        = "vallabhherlekar@gmail.com"
    to          = "vallabhherlekar@gmail.com"
    subject     = "test"
    smtpserver  = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port        = "587"
    attachments = $f.FullName
    
    body        = "test msg"
    }
Send-MailMessage @hash -Credential $Cred -UseSsl

Comment: Above code using Send-MailMessage sends only the last file from each sub-folder as an attachment in each separate email. I want it to send all files in each sub-folder. I'd appreciate anyone's help with suggesting modifications to my code.